# Caliburn.Micro view not destroyed in Popup

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I've run across an issue when I close a popup created with Caliburn micro : The view doesn't seem to be destroyed.

I use Caliburn.Micro 2.0.1 with MEF, you can see my exemple here :
https://github.com/louisfish/BaseCaliburn

Basically, I create a window with a button inside. 
When you click on this button, a new window is opened with the ShowWindow function of WindowManager.
In this popup, I created a message with a binding.
I put output traces when my message is get in my ViewModel.

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BaseCaliburn.ViewModels
{
    [Export]
    public class PopupViewModel : Screen
    {
        private int _timesOpened;
        private string _message;
        public string Message
        {
            get 
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Message is get");
                return _message; 
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == _message) return;
                _message = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Message);
            }
        }
        protected override void OnActivate()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("---Window is activated---");
            _timesOpened++;

            Message = "Popup number : " + _timesOpened;
        }      
    }
}
```

Each time I open and close my window, the old binding stays there.
So after 5 open/close, I have 5 call to my get Message in my ViewModel.

So I receive the binding of the old views:

```
Message is get
---Window is activated---
Message is get
Message is get
Message is get
Message is get
Message is get
```

Comment: 2 things possible, 1) you are not calling TryClose(true) on closure of your popupview, this should close the viewmodel and "kill it", and since you are using MEF, there is ```[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)```, by default MEF creates all parts with PartCreationPolicy = Shared which equivalent to "Singleton"

Comment: I tried adding [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)] to my PopupViewModel and the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have one single instance of `HomeViewModel`. You're having your main window bound to the `HomeViewModel`, so every time you click `StartApp`, the method is called on the same instance.
- This instance has a `PopupViewModel` property, which is initialized by your dependency injection container as soon as the `HomeViewModel` gets created. Then, it stays the same. Every time your `StartApp` method gets the value of the property, the same instance of `PopupViewModel` is returned.
- What you actually want is a new `PopupViewModel` instance every time you call `StartApp`. You need a factory. In MEF, you can import `ExportFactory<T>` to create instances on demand:

  ```
  [Import]
  public ExportFactory<PopupViewModel> PopupViewModelFactory { get; set; }

  public void StartApp()
  {
      Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;

      PopupViewModel newPopup = this.PopupViewModelFactory.CreateExport().Value;
      IoC.Get<IWindowManager>().ShowWindow(newPopup);
  }
  ```